# How do I access the application icon's context menu with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey, context-menu

I'm afraid I don't really know what this special menu is called, but I'd like to activate one of the menu items here from an AutoHotKey script.

[image: screenshot]

I'm trying to get at `Clear Scrollback`.

Again, I don't know the term for this menu so searching wasn't too helpful.  (Turns out `application icon context menu` isn't all that specific.)  If this is a duplicate anywhere, I'd be more than happy with that.

Comment: Someone who shares my name came up with [an alleged solution](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15477-accessing-the-system-menu-using-winmenuselectitem/), but I feel like ten years is plenty of time for new syntax to have been introduced.

Comment: So... does that code not work? Why is new syntax required (assuming it even exists)?

Comment: @Karan I'll try it out here shortly -- personally, I'd prefer a more abstract syntax than asking Windows for the handle and calling DLLs with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Normally using the keyboard you can activate the system menu with `{Alt Down}{Alt Up}{Space}`.  The DLL code is much nicer though since it's programmatic and no keystrokes required.

In your case I believe you would just be setting `n=17` since dividers count as a menu items.  Code worked for me this way, although I selected other items such as the event viewer just to see if worked, not a test on clearing the scrollback specifically.